# Message "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required." for "pip install ccxt"

Tags: pip, python-packaging, ccxt

While downloading `pip install ccxt`, I faced this problem:

```
        check.warn(importable)
      copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      running build_ext
      building 'multidict._multidict' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have tried:
`pip install multidict`

and it still not working.

I am using Python 3.12.0 on Windows 11.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried following the advice in the error message: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ ? Have you rerun he `pip install ccxt` afterwards?

Comment: this package is officially supported up to python 3.11, so try using a different python version.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at PyPi, [CCXT](https://pypi.org/project/ccxt/) and [Multidict](https://pypi.org/project/multidict/) currently supports Python 3 versions 3.7 - 3.11. There's no support yet for Python 3.12.0. So you may want to downgrade to a supported version.

Instead of uninstalling python 3.12.0, I would suggest using a [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) to do this.